# Slick-Slider, как на маленьком экране сделать 1 слайд, на большом 4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте!

Как сделать на большом экране 4 слайда, а на маленьком 1?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас это дело выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
<div class="top10slider">
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                        <img src="img/bottomslider/photo-4.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Онофрейчук Алла</h4>
                        <h3>57 888</h3>
                        <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                        <img src="img/bottomslider/photo-2.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Воин Дмитрий</h4>
                        <h3>77 651</h3>
                        <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                        <img src="img/bottomslider/photo-1.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Онофрейчук Петр</h4>
                        <h3>4 655</h3>
                        <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                        <img src="img/bottomslider/photo-3.png" alt="">
                        <h4>Берестовая Татьяна</h4>
                        <h3>7 108</h3>
                        <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6531.png" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <h3>12 108</h3>
                    <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6531.png" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <h3>12 108</h3>
                    <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6531.png" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <h3>12 108</h3>
                    <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
                <div class="top10slider__slide col-md-3">
                    <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6531.png" alt="">
                    <h4>John Doe</h4>
                    <h3>12 108</h3>
                    <p>переходов по ссылкам</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.top10slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    arrows: true,
});
```

CSS:

```
div.top10slider {
  text-align: center;
  h4 {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #520090;
    font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
  img {
    display: inline;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в слайдер добавить опцию `responsive`:

```
$('.top10slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 6,
  slidesToScroll: 6,
  arrows: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Из примера выше следует, что по умолчанию будет отображаться 6 слайдов, при разрешении экрана ниже 1024 пикселей - 4 слайда, при ниже 600 пикселей - 2 слайда.